# Unable to connect to MS SQL 2012 database on Debian 8 with FreeTDS

Tags: debian, odbc, freetds

I've been trying for two days to get my Debian 8 Google Cloud machine to connect to a Microsoft SQL 2012 database. I know the database is okay, because I have no trouble doing this in Windows. Now I'm trying to move some website code written in Python from Windows to Debian, but I'm unable to access the database that is the whole point of the website.

Of course, I've been doing a *lot* of searching on this topic. As so often happens, I've found conflicting information, and each guide that says it's the "right" one has failed me. Best of all, the 
[FreeTDS email list](http://lists.ibiblio.org/mailman/listinfo/freetds)
 isn't up, or at the very least, is auto-rejecting new subscribers.

As I said, I'm on Debian 8, on a GCloud server. SCP isn't working because of authentication key problems, so I have only shell access and can only copy to or from the Home directory. I've installed UnixODBC, tdsodbc, and freetds, plus a few more packages I've found people suggested. This was all with `sudo apt-get`, not from source or direct from any website.

My files aren't in `/etc`, they're in `/etc/freetds`. I've also found some guides that say I need to `sudo cp /etc/freetds/freetds.conf ~/.freetds.conf`. Note the "." at the start of the destination filename. I also have `/etc/freetds/odbc.ini`, which defines my DSN. In `freetds.conf`, I define a database entry, and the "Databasename" in `odbc.ini` option is set to the same value as the section name in `freetds.conf`. I have my driver defined in `/etc/odbcinst.ini` (no, I don't know why that's in /etc but the others are in `/etc/freetds`). Below I've pasted my three files. Note that I've removed comments from the first one, to make things a bit shorter here. The comments are intact in the actual file.

I had the Setup line in there as well as a few others, but 
[one post I found](https://ubuntu4questions.wordpress.com/2015/01/01/connecting-ms-sql-using-freetds-and-unixodbc-isql-no-default-driver-specified/) 
said it works better without that and several other lines.

Here's the fun part: tsql works perfectly--it connects if I do `tsql -S DBName -U username`, but `isql` fails every time, with the same error. It's always

```
[IM002][unixodbc][driver manager] No data source name found, and no default driver specified. 
[ISQLERROR]: Could not SQLConnect.
```

If I give `isql` the name of a database that's not defined at all, I get the exact same error. For instance, I'd get the `IM002` error with

```
isql -v testabc
```

This suggests to me that something isn't finding all the `configuration/ini` files it needs. But `tsql works`, while `isql` (and, of course, my Python script) don't work. I'm new to Debian, and have only SSH access to this Debian machine, so I can't use GUI tools to make this easier. I'm reasonably comfortable in Bash and VIM, I just don't know what packages are looking where for what files. I also don't know what options I should take out or put back in, if any, to get things working.

Comment: I think I have it. On a whim, I tried sudo cp /etc/freetds/odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini. As soon as I did that, isql worked, then my Python script worked. So, I guess my post is more of a guide, but be sure to put odbc.ini in /etc if you're on a Debian 8 system. Maybe other systems too, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

To get this working, the configuration detailed in my first post actually works fine. The only problem is that `odbc.ini` is in the wrong place.
`sudo cp /etc/freetds/odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini` 
will do the trick. Or just put `odbc.ini` (which you may have to create) in `/etc` in the first place. Apparently only `freetds.conf` belongs in `/etc/freetds`.